# Delphi 7: Store TStrings into SQLite3 database field

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-7

I am using Delphi 7 and SQLite3 database. And I am using this simple wrapper for accessing SQLite3:

http://www.itwriting.com/blog/articles/a-simple-delphi-wrapper-for-sqlite-3/

My question, I want to store a TStrings data into a field, and retrieve it later.

Anyone can show me some codes?

Comment: look at how they store Notes here http://www.itwriting.com/repos/sqlitewrapper/trunk/uTestSqlite.pas and use TStringList.Text to set/get the text to/from the TStringList variable

Comment: Yes, apparently, I can store using TStrings.GetText and use "TEXT" field type in SQLite3. To retrieve just use the same fieldbyname which result in string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

First, the SQLite3 field should be created as "TEXT" field type.

To store: Use the TStrings.GetText

To retrieve: Use TStrings.Add(SQLtable.FieldByName['THETEXT']);

That works:)

Comment: You should use .Text := SQLtable.FieldByName['THETEXT']; instead